# PowerShell script, writing CloudWatch metrics, throws error on first time, works after

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell, amazon-cloudwatch

I have a simple PowerShell script that is running on an EC2 instance (running Windows), and sends metrics to CloudWatch.

Here's the code in question:

```
if ($metrics && $metrics.Length) {
    Write-Host "Writing metrics [$($metrics.Length)] for namespace '$($Namespace)' to CloudWatch."

    Write-CWMetricData -Namespace $Namespace -MetricData $metrics
} else {
    Write-Error "No metrics to report."
}
```

and here's the output:

````
Writing metrics [2] for namespace 'service-monitor' to CloudWatch.
Write-CWMetricData: C:\Users\Public\Documents\service-monitor.ps1:159
Line |
 159 |          Write-CWMetricData -Namespace $Namespace -MetricData $metrics
     |          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | Object reference not set to an instance of an object.```
````

The line of code is within a loop, and subsequent iterations do not report an error. The metrics are recorded successfully.

I can live with the error, it's just puzzling.